# Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container

Tags: java-swing, jframe, warnings

al momento de ejecutar mi proyecto me sale este error:  "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container"
Estoy realizando una interfaz en la que muestre una ventana llamada Ver_Roles en un panel llamado panelContenido que esta ubicado en una ventana llamada Roles al momento de dar click en un botón.
Este es el fragmento de código que utilizo para querer mostrar la ventana de Ver_Roles.  No quiero utilizar el JInternalFrame.

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    Ver_Roles roles = new Ver_Roles();
    //roles.setSize(520, 428);
    roles.setLocation(0,0);
    
    panelContenido.removeAll();
    panelContenido.add(roles, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panelContenido.revalidate();
    panelContenido.repaint();
}
```